# Admin/Customer Roles (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, admin

I'm currently working on a website that is for a restaurant. I have created everything I need to but I'm confused on one part:

I have created two roles: Admin and Customer. I have a page that displays a menu.

My main problem is, how would I display this page to the customer as a simple menu page, and how would I display this page to the admin where he would be able to edit the items within the database?

Would I need to create two different pages, one for a standard customer and one for the admin, or could it be done through the sitemap, where a link (the edit menu page) is visible/invisible based on the user who is signed in? (How would I accomplish that?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your custom code for this, as you have yourself created two roles. you can use the following steps

1) Create form authentication ticket for your roles on login and add it so that you'll be able to authenticate user/roles and write authentication rules in web.config.

2) either create two different page for admin and customer or you can use single page that renders differently based on the role, if you creates a single page make sure you should hide secure admin menu items at server side itself so that it will not be rendered and thus no change can be made at client side for security reason or just add items based on roles dynamically always.

Let me know if you need more details.